# Why getting cannot read properties of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, frontend, getelementbyid

I have a react app in which I am supposed to get users from an API endpoint: <reqres.in>.

I am supposed to return as many buttons on the homepage as the number of users I get on fetching the users from the API.

Also I am constrained not to add event listeners to all buttons and just add one listener to the wrapper for the buttons. The code for the same is:

```
const ButtonContainer = ({ users }) => {
    // const navigate=useNavigate();
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
        if (!isButton) {
            return;
        }
        // navigate(`/singleuser/${event.target.id}`);
    })

    return (
        <div id='wrapper'>
            {
                users.map((user, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <button key={idx} id={idx}>
                            User {idx}
                        </button>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ButtonContainer
```

users is the array of users Im getting from the API.

However I am getting the error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where's code for `wrapper`, also you have a html element with `wrapper` id  ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('wrapper')`, your `wrapper` element doesn't exist yet so trying to get a reference to it there will just return `null`. Also you shouldn't be using the native dom methods unless absolutely necessary. You should be using the react way, adding the event through the `onClick` property of your wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using native DOM methods with React won't give you the result you want as React has its own way of managing the DOM.

Add an `onClick` to your wrapper element:

```
<div onClick={handleClick}>
```

and then have `handleClick` deal with the event.

```js
function Example({ users }) {

  function handleClick(e) {

    // Because we're using event delegation [1]
    // check if the clicked element was a user button
    if (e.target.matches('button.user')) {

      // Extract the id from its dataset,
      // and log it
      const { id } = e.target.dataset;
      console.log(`User: ${id}`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {users.map(user => {
        return (
          <button
            key={user.id}
            className="user"
            data-id={user.id}
          >User: {user.id}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

const users = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example users={users} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```